# Query response in JSON format without column name

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table schema is something like this,

```
DECLARE @mytable AS TABLE(ID INT, EmpName VARCHAR(10), Age INT);

INSERT INTO @mytable
VALUES
(1,     'a', 1),
(2,     'b', 2),
(3,     'c', 3),
(4,     'd', 4),
(5,     'e', 5),
(6,     'f', 6),
(7,     'g', 7),
(8,     'h', 8),
(9,     'i', 9),
(10,    'j', 10);
```

Initially, my procedure was returning with data as

```
SELECT ID, EmpName, Age FROM @mytable;
```

After processing the data, to the web page is sent as

```
[{1,"a",1},
{2,"b",2},
{3,"c",3},
{4,"d",4},
{5,"e",5},
{6,"f",6},
{7,"g",7},
{8,"h",8},
{9,"i",9},
{10,"j",10}]
```

If I use

```
SELECT ID, EmpName, Age
FROM @mytable
FOR JSON AUTO;
```

the result will be like

```
[{"ID":1,"EmpName":"a","Age":1},
 {"ID":2,"EmpName":"b","Age":2},
 {"ID":3,"EmpName":"c","Age":3},
 {"ID":4,"EmpName":"d","Age":4},
 {"ID":5,"EmpName":"e","Age":5},
 {"ID":6,"EmpName":"f","Age":6},
 {"ID":7,"EmpName":"g","Age":7},
 {"ID":8,"EmpName":"h","Age":8},
 {"ID":9,"EmpName":"i","Age":9},
 {"ID":10,"EmpName":"j","Age":10}]
```

So what I need to get is the same response but without column name, as front-end lib uses the JSON array without keys.

SQL Server version 2012 is used.

I hope I am clear on my end. Thanks.

Comment: @gotqn, Sorry, my home computer have sql server 2017 installed so I did not realize that it will not work on 2012 on which the project DB is. Any other options?

Comment: @Harsh . . . If you are using your home computer for development, you might want to learn about database compatibility levels:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level?view=sql-server-2017.

Comment: @GordonLinoff No, I am not using my home computer for development but since I was stuck with the problem in office so I was trying to solve it during weekend. About changing compatibility level, I will change that in my home PC's database. Thanks for the input. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT STUFF
(
    (
        SELECT CONCAT(',{', ID, ', "', EmpName, '", ', age, '}')
        FROM @mytable
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'varchar(max)')
    ,1
    ,1
    ,'['
) + ']';
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the "select to a variable" trick to build the string.

```
declare @JsonesceString varchar(max);

select @JsonesceString = concat(@JsonesceString+','+char(10),'{',ID,',"',EmpName,'",',age,'}')
from @mytable
order by ID;

select concat('[',@JsonesceString,']') as Result;
```

Returns the value:

```
[{1,"a",1},
{2,"b",2},
{3,"c",3},
{4,"d",4},
{5,"e",5},
{6,"f",6},
{7,"g",7},
{8,"h",8},
{9,"i",9},
{10,"j",10}]
```