# SQL TABLE to JSON without SQL Column Information

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to Parse Table data into JSON and in the process want to skip the Table Column Names in the Post conversion to JSON. Below is the sample Snippet.

```
DECLARE @table1 TABLE (k1 nvarchar(max), v1 nvarchar(max))

-- Note k1 is unique
INSERT INTO @table1 (k1,v1) VALUES( 'Apple', 'One')
INSERT INTO @table1 (k1,v1) VALUES( 'Banana', 'Two')
INSERT INTO @table1 (k1,v1) VALUES( 'Orange', 'Three')

SELECT k1, v1 FROM @table1
    FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER

--output: {"k1":"Apple","v1":"One"},{"k1":"Banana","v1":"Two"},{"k1":"Orange","v1":"Three"}
-- Expected: {"Apple","One"},{"Banana","Two"},{"Orange","Three"}
```

Appreciate direction!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Query response in JSON format without column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54501747/query-response-in-json-format-without-column-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

--string concatenation&aggregation (string_agg() for sql2017&later or for xml path() for sql2016)

```
select string_agg(concat('{"', string_escape(k1, 'json'), '":"', string_escape(v1, 'json'), '"}'), ',') /*within group (order by k1)*/
from @table1
```